# Parametrise controller to work in different directives

Tags: angularjs

I need to work with several different directives in angularJS. The directives have different templates and the controllers should work in very similar way, with very small changes each-other.

I was thinking to use just one shared controller that adapt its behaviour to the directive it's included like the idea described in code:

```
var module = angular.module('app', []);

module.directive('myFirstDirective', function () {
    return {
        scope: {},
        controller: 'MyController',
        templateUrl: './directives/first.html'
    };
});

module.directive('mySecondDirective', function () {
    return {
        scope: {},
        controller: 'MyController',
        templateUrl: './directives/second.html'
    };
});
module.controller('MyController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.myEvent = function () {
        //if it's first directive do this
        //if it's second directive do that
    };
});
```

Is there any way in angular to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ng-init="callback1()"` and `ng-init="callback2()"` in your directives. And describe both callbacks in your controller.

Comment: Sorry but the answer is not clear for me, do you mean to do something like `<my-first-directive ng-init="callback1()">` and `<my-second-directive ng-init="callback2()">`? If so I prefer a different solution because I prefer to avoid to duplicate every time the same `ng-init` param (and value) in all directive use.

My first idea was `<directive param="directive1">` but I didn't like this one as well.

Comment: You can use `ng-init` in your templates `./directives/first.html` and `./directives/second.html`, so you should't pass it every time to `<my-first-directive` and `<my-second-directive`